# My java code's ouput is not as expected?

Tags: java

The following is my java code.

```
public class TestVolatile {

    static class Test {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
            final Test test = new Test();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    test.a = 1; //test.a assignment before test.b assignment
                    test.b = 1;
                }
            }).start();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("a="+test.a+",b="+test.b);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to find out all possible output with `java com.company.test_volatile.TestVolatile | sort -u`. But there are only three results without `a=1, b=0`.

> a=0, b=0
>   a=0, b=1
>   a=1, b=1

No matter how many times I run the code, always get the same result. So what's the reason of no output `a=1, b=0`? Does the synchronization of `println` do with it?

Comment: Look up thread interleaving. Just because two threads are started one after the other, they won't be guaranteed to execute in that same order. So the thread that sets the variables might run 9000 times before the system decides to switch to the print thread. Or it might happen after it set one variable which is why the output has `a=0, b=1` etc

Comment: I tried running your program and I get 77% a=1, b=1, and 23% a=0, b=0, with just a tiny number of a=0, b=1, and _no_ a=1, b=0 results.  So this seems to be implementation- and machine-dependent.

Comment: What do you think the code is doing? You could step through it in a debugger and / or add some additional output. To be more. Specific, yoy said the output is not as expected. What do you expect?

Comment: already update my question.

Comment: Why are you calling it `TestVolatile` when you're not using `volatile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to bruteforce it. There might have been a better way. I got an output with a=1, b=0.

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do java TestVolatile | grep 'a=1,b=0'; done                                                                                                   
a=1,b=0
a=1,b=0
a=1,b=0
a=1,b=0
a=1,b=0
```

Its still going on. I'll update if I get more

Update: I got 5 matches from running 1000 * 1000 times. So the probability of this output is extremely low. As to why is it so, I guess its machine dependent.

Comment: I still cannot get the output by running your shell code, but I think you are right.

Comment: My enviroment is unbuntu 16.04 64bit, oracle jdk 18

Comment: finally I get it.